# Unable to refer to typedef struct definitions done in Win32 Header files (.h files in External dependencies) from WinRT C++ Library

Tags: c++, winapi, struct, typedef, c++-winrt

Unable to refer to typedef struct definitions done in Win32 Header files (.h files in External dependencies) when consumed from WinRT C++ Library

```
#include <mfplay.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"Mfplay.lib") 
class MediaPlayerCallback //: public IMFPMediaPlayerCallback
{
long m_cRef; // Reference count
MFP_EVENT_HEADER H;
};
```

MFP_EVENT_HEADER is a typedef struct defined inside MFPlay.h, Doing a Go to the definition in VS2019 takes me to the definition in MFPlay.h definition but the code doesn't compile

But I tried creating a typedef struct in a .h file I have created and I'm able to compile that without any issues.

My doubt is why am I not able to compile when defined in MFPlay.h but able to compile when defined in header files defined by me.

**The error I'm getting**

```
MediaPlayerCallback.h(11,22): error C3646: 'H': unknown override specifier
MediaPlayerCallback.h(11,23): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

[Minimum Reproducible](https://github.com/PrithviVenu/MFPlayIssue_MinimumReproducible/tree/master)

**Already Tried-**
Tried the same code on the win32 desktop app and I'm able to compile without any issues but when doing the same thing from a WinRT C++ library getting this issue

Comment: Please include the exact error message you get when compiling

Comment: @UnholySheep, have updated my question with the error details shown in the output window

Comment: If I understand the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mfplay/ns-mfplay-mfp_event_header) correctly then MFP in general is not supported in WinRT, only in Win32. So you will have to use a different Windows Media technology, that is actually supported

Comment: @UnholySheep, since WinRT allows consumption of win32 APIs without interop in the uwp app, this must also be possible.
I'm able to consume most other win32 apis without issues in WinRT component, just wondering why i'm not able to do this.
Note - I'm able to consume the MFPlay.h library as well, just getting problems with the typedef structs defined in the MFPlay.h

Comment: The whole MfPlay.h content is surrounded by `#if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP) #if (WINVER >= _WIN32_WINNT_WIN7)`. They are probably not defined in your project somehow, especially the WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP requirement` (classic win32 desktop app, not UWP, not phone, etc.)

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. This would specifically require that you analyze and strip down the command line your IDE passes to the compiler.

Comment: @IInspectable, https://github.com/PrithviVenu/MFPlayIssue_MinimumReproducible/tree/master
This link has minimum reproducible example

Comment: Like I said, these are UWP projects, not win32 classic desktop projects, you can't use MfPlay. PS: don't confuse WinRT and UWP (although yes, it's confusing :-)

Comment: Hi @SimonMourier , There are two libraries in my example one is uwp and other is winrt, I'm referring to this winrt library from the uwp library, My question is regarding winrt library

Comment: They are both UWP "Universal Windows" https://i.imgur.com/IdNS5f0.png

Comment: Hi @SimonMourier , The WinRT Library is a windows run time component in c++, that is also a part of Universal Windows
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/intro-to-using-cpp-with-winrt , from WinRT we can consume Win32 Apis, we just can't use it in IDL and consume it from UWP, but from inside WinRT Library we must be able to consume Win32 Api's

Comment: You can' use desktop-only APIs, such as MFplay, from UWP code such as your components. This is not related with C++/WinRT but how the SDK works. Your component is of "Windows Store" type which will cause WINAPI_FAMILY to be defined as WINAPI_FAMILY_APP which means it's *not* a win32 classic desktop type code. Try to redefine WINAPI_FAMILY in the PCH instead and make sure you've set the "Windows Desktop Compatible" option to "Yes" : https://i.imgur.com/9iw0EoG.png Not sure it will work in the end, we're in an ever changing territory... https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues/58

Comment: As Simon explains, you are targeting the UWP. [`MPF_EVENT_HEADER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mfplay/ns-mfplay-mfp_event_header) is marked as *"desktop apps only"* (see the Requirements section). It is thus unavailable. The SDK headers make sure that it isn't defined, and that's what the compiler is trying to tell you. Of course, you *can* implement a Windows Runtime Component that targets the Win32 API (aka classic desktop). While you can reference that component from a UWP app, you won't be able to ship it. It will fail store certification.

Comment: @SimonMourier, Set Desktop Compatible property to yes, that didn't help, should I add anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the issue is that the `MFP_EVENT_HEADER` type is in the `WINAPI_FAMILY_DESKTOP_APP` API partition but is *not* in the `WINAPI_FAMILY_APP` API partition supported for UWP applications. Per [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mfplay/ns-mfplay-mfp_event_header) this type is marked " [desktop apps only]".

`IMFPMediaPlayerCallback` is also "desktop apps only". This is because this API is considered deprecated per [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mfplay/nn-mfplay-imfpmediaplayercallback). The recommendation is to use [Media Session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/media-session) APIs instead although `IMFMediaSession` is *also* a desktop only interface.

For UWP, the list of Media Foundation APIs supported is found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/win32-and-com/win32-apis#apis-from-mfdll). There is also the `Windows.Media` Windows Runtime API surface. I recommend starting with [Audio, video, and camera](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/) and see what is supported for your scenario.